# Big Query remove days

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a Big Query table called `historical` with 2 columns `date` and `score`. `date` is a `string` such as `2015-11-07 23:00:00` and `score` an `integer` between `0` and `100`. I read the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#date_add) because I would like to remove 7 days from a given date and the example showed on the documentation is not working:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP("2012-10-01 02:03:04"), 7, "YEAR");
```

What would be the easiest way to remove 7 days from `"2012-10-01 02:03:04"` with the same format?

Comment: Are you using standard SQL or legacy?

Comment: When you say, remove 7 days, do you mean subtract 7 days (EG March 8 -> March 1)?

Comment: Yes, correct subtract 7 days! And I am not sure which SQL. I am using to be honest

Comment: It looks like you already have a good answer below. You might consider updating the title for clarity. Something like this might help others in the future: `Subtract N days from date in Big Query`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
format_datetime('%F %T', datetime_sub(parse_datetime('%F %T', date), interval 7 day))
```

so, first you parse datetime out of string, then you substruct 7 days and finally you format datetime back to string

Comment: Amazing sir! You are the expert